# Pseudo code Algorithm help for swapping/comparing values

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, pseudocode

I am struggling with the solution for this algorithm problem with a cost estimator I am trying to make, if anyone could help me with any pseudo code it would be a great help.

> I have three inputs x, y and z. The inputs each have a separate max
>   value that if breached return an  error.  These values X = 230 Y = 190
>   Z = 330.
>
> Now I need a function that compares the in-putted values and if
>   possible swaps the values to keep them under the constraints. Also Z
>   should always contain the smallest value as long as the swapped value
>   still meets the max value constraints.
>
> So for a few examples if the user entered X=10,Y=30,Z=30 the values
>   for X and Z would be swapped to make z the lowest value. With X=180
>   Y=220 Z=30 X and Y would be swapped to fit under max values. With
>   X=100 Y=120 Z=50 nothing would be swapped. X=310 Y=320 Z=100 nothing
>   would be swapped and you would get an error.

I hope I have made myself clear any help would be greatly appreciated.

F

Comment: What did you try ? If you are really looking at this 3 variable case, you could generate the 6 possible permutations, order them by Z-value (with the original one in first position), and returns the first one that satisfies all the constraint

Comment: I only have a function that swaps z with smallest value regardless of the constraints. I am working on a codepen now to better explain.

Comment: What would be the 6 possible permutations?

Answer (score 1):

So your code could be the following :

```
let a be an array of size 6 containing 3-uplets
let a[1] = (x,y,z)
let a[2] = (x,z,y)
let a[3] = (z,y,x)
let a[4] = (y,z,x)
let a[5] = (z,x,y)
let a[6] = (y,x,z)
sort a by the last value of 3-uplet, in increasing order
for (int i = 1; i <6; i++) {
    if a[i] satisfies all the constraints return a[i];
}
return "no solution found"
```

Besides if you use a stable sort this algorithm guarantees that you will get a solution with as few transpositions as possible.